# Openlayers 2 and JSTS (JavaScript Topology Suite)

Tags: openlayers

Im' using an open source web mapping application (geOrchestra).

It uses Openlayers 2.14

When I try to use last JSTS library, it doesn't work (I already used it and worked well with a Openlayers 5.3 application).

In the JSTS example, they use "feature.getGeometry()" but there's no such method in Openlayers 2.
Also, "new OpenLayersParser()" doesn't exist in the latest JSTS library.

I can't find any example on internet to help me.

Is OpenLayers 2 incompatible with latest JSTS ?
If yes, is there an old JSTS library that is Openlayers 2 compatible ?

Any advice ?

Comment: I think you would need to convert the OpenLayers 2 feature geometry to and from GeoJSON format using `OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON` and then use `jts.io.GeoJSONReader` and `jts.io.GeoJSONWriter` to go to and from JSTS

Comment: Thanks for that info.

I found this : http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL210/JSTS_Example/jsts_example.asp

Comment: Thanks for that info.

I found this : http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL210/JSTS_Example/jsts_example.asp

I downloaded jsts.js and javacript.util.js from that site and I could make it work without using JSON.

Now, as the projection of my map is EPSG:3857, when I measure the buffer distance processed by JSTS, it's not accurate depending on the latitude :

In north of Spain, a circle created with a 5000 meters buffer from a point has a diameter of approximately 7km.
The same buffer in north of England is approximately 6km...

What is correct ? OL measure tool or JSTS ?

Comment: It seems like JSTS is using projection units and if you want the buffer to be distance on the ground you need to compensate for latitude.  Just as Greenland isn't really as big as Africa a circle at 60 degree latitude which appears to be the same size as one on the equator on the map is only half the diameter on the ground, so you need to divide the required distance by cos(latitude) to get the projection units you need to represent it on the map.

Comment: Looks like OL measuring tool is wrong by comparing it with the coordinates on the map: processing coordinates gives same results as the JSTS buffers.
In others words : don't trust OL measuging tool. (Openlayers 2)

Comment: When using JSTS, I don't think we have to compensate with cos(latitude).
Like I said before, buffer size is correct when we look at coordinates X,Y (in EPSG:3857) on a OL 2 map.
OL 2 measuring tool is wrong...

Comment: EPSG:3857 coordinates do not represent true distance.  The measuring tool should show Greenland is about 1200km across at the widest point, while Africa is over 7000km across.